# Moderator message is not responsive on mobile

Tags: bug, responsive-design, moderator-messages, mobile-firefox

I received a message from the moderators, but it's rather hard to read on my mobile (Firefox on IOS 16.3.1, iPhone 12 Mini) because the text is wider than the viewport.

Wasn't the whole "responsive" design supposed to allow the content to be viewed on units with different dimensions anyway?

Here are a couple of screenshots. I am unable to zoom out to view the text without horizontal scrolling.

[image: Top of message]

[image: Bottom]

Comment: For what it's worth, the email message I also received had an HTML version which rendered fine, but the `text/plain` version (which is my preferred format) had a lot of <p>HTML <div>markup</div></p>

Comment: Not everything is responsive *yet* - so I guess this is one of those things :D

Comment: Responsive design is being deployed in stages, first the user profile then the questions listing and the posts. As Geek said we can assume the PM box hasn't been made responsive yet, I just searched through the responsive tag and couldn't find a previous announcement or bug report about this.

Comment: Fun fact: It's responsive the other way around, if you're a moderator viewing/issuing a mod message.

Comment: It looks like that interface could use an update. I thought that triangle was was a play button so I thought you received an audio message. Now I see it's an arrow pointing from moderators to you.

Comment: Its a play button. It plays Never gonna give you up in an unstoppable loop. Cuts down on reoffenders (no not really)